# Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer - Tomcat initiating

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm having trouble starting my Spring Boot app on TomCat 9.
In Intellij IDE the application starts and works as expected.

When I try to start the application via TomCat Web Application Manager, I get the message:

**FAIL - Application in context path [/bedelServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] could not be started**

Tomcat Log

```
09-Apr-2019 16:43:34.260 GRAVE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1858)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:772)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:503)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
    ... 40 more
```

This is my main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BwsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private ConfigClass config;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logs.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BwsApplication.class);
    }

    public BwsApplication(ConfigClass configClass) {
        config = configClass;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BwsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = config.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
        }
        QuartzApp qa = new QuartzApp(config);
        qa.excecution();
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.speedsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>bedelServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!--    <packaging>jar</packaging>-->
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>bedel</name>
    <description>BWS</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
        <jooq.version>3.9.1</jooq.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <logbackaccess.version>1.3.0-alpha4</logbackaccess.version>
        <mysql.version>6.0.3</mysql.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin>1.7</exec-maven-plugin>

        <start-class>com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>${logbackaccess.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.speedsoft.bws.BwsApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--plugin exe-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>

            <!-- inserida para teste -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>

            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am creating .war using the command: *clean package*

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.1.0:war (default-war) @ bedelServer ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [bedelServer] in [C:\Projetos\BedelServer\target\bedelServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [16175 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Projetos\BedelServer\target\bedelServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ bedelServer ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.370 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-09T17:51:20-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 51M/662M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is it something related to the constructor of my main class?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
private ConfigClass config;
```

remove the

```
public BwsApplication (ConfigClass configClass) {
    config = configClass;
}
```